# Neo4j: Applying index and constraint changes query results

Tags: neo4j, cypher, constraints, database-indexes

I am encountering an issue with Neo4j where the results for the same query change after applying the below:

- an index on a property for nodes with a given label
- a constraint that asserts the existence of the same property for nodes with the same label as above

##### Environment

- Neo4j version: 4.2.1 Enterprise, default runtime (slotted)
- Neo4j Desktop 1.4.1
- Operating system: macOS Big Sur Version 11.4

##### Steps to reproduce:

Create one set of nodes and relationships by running the following:

```
CREATE (p1:Person { id: '100', name: 'Hampton Fancher' })<-[:WRITTEN_BY]-(m:Movie { id: '101', name: 'Blade Runner' })-[:BASED_ON]->(n:Novel { id: '102', name: 'Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?' })-[:WRITTEN_BY]->(p2:Person { id: '103', name: 'Philip K Dick' })
```

Create a second set of nodes and relationships by running the following:

```
CREATE (p1:Person { id: '200', name: 'Phil Alden Robinson' })<-[:WRITTEN_BY]-(m:Movie { id: '201', name: 'Field of Dreams' })-[:BASED_ON]->(n:Novel { id: '202', name: 'Shoeless Joe' })-[:WRITTEN_BY]->(p2:Person { id: '203', name: 'W P Kinsella' })
```

Run this query:

```
MATCH (movie:Movie { name: 'Blade Runner' })

OPTIONAL MATCH (movie)-[:WRITTEN_BY|BASED_ON]->(entity)
    WHERE entity:Person OR entity:Novel

OPTIONAL MATCH (entity:Novel)-[:WRITTEN_BY]->(sourceNovelWriter:Person)

RETURN sourceNovelWriter
```

The results are as expected (i.e. they reflect Philip K Dick as the source novel writer of Blade Runner):

```
╒═══════════════════════════════════╕
│"sourceNovelWriter"                │
╞═══════════════════════════════════╡
│{"name":"Philip K Dick","id":"103"}│
├───────────────────────────────────┤
│null                               │
└───────────────────────────────────┘
```

Then create an index for the `name` property for nodes with the `Novel` label:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Novel(name)
```

Then create a constraint on the existence of the `name` property for nodes with the `Novel` label:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Novel) ASSERT EXISTS(n.name)
```

N.B. The following behaviour is only experienced when both the index and constraint are applied; if only one is applied then it does not occur.

Re-running the initial query shows that the results have changed to as shown below and which are not expected (i.e. they incorrectly state that W P Kinsella is a source novel writer of Blade Runner):

```
╒═══════════════════════════════════╕
│"sourceNovelWriter"                │
╞═══════════════════════════════════╡
│{"name":"Philip K Dick","id":"103"}│
├───────────────────────────────────┤
│{"name":"W P Kinsella","id":"203"} │
├───────────────────────────────────┤
│{"name":"Philip K Dick","id":"103"}│
├───────────────────────────────────┤
│{"name":"W P Kinsella","id":"203"} │
└───────────────────────────────────┘
```

The query can be fixed by removing the `Novel` label from the second `OPTIONAL MATCH` (but it would be preferred to have the added explicitness of expressing that the match is only required when the `entity` variable has a `Novel` label):

```
MATCH (movie:Movie { name: 'Blade Runner' })

OPTIONAL MATCH (movie)-[:WRITTEN_BY|BASED_ON]->(entity)
    WHERE entity:Person OR entity:Novel

OPTIONAL MATCH (entity)-[:WRITTEN_BY]->(sourceNovelWriter:Person)

RETURN sourceNovelWriter
```

This returns:

```
╒═══════════════════════════════════╕
│"sourceNovelWriter"                │
╞═══════════════════════════════════╡
│{"name":"Philip K Dick","id":"103"}│
├───────────────────────────────────┤
│null                               │
└───────────────────────────────────┘
```

The `entity` variable can be examined by revising the query to make it the return value:

```
MATCH (movie:Movie { name: 'Blade Runner' })

OPTIONAL MATCH (movie)-[:WRITTEN_BY|BASED_ON]->(entity)
    WHERE entity:Person OR entity:Novel

OPTIONAL MATCH (entity:Novel)-[:WRITTEN_BY]->(sourceNovelWriter:Person)

RETURN entity
```

This incorrectly includes `Shoeless Joe` in the results:

```
╒══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"entity"                                                  │
╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│{"name":"Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?","id":"102"}│
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│{"name":"Shoeless Joe","id":"202"}                        │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│{"name":"Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?","id":"102"}│
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│{"name":"Shoeless Joe","id":"202"}                        │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

If the second `OPTIONAL MATCH` is removed, i.e.

```
MATCH (movie:Movie { name: 'Blade Runner' })

OPTIONAL MATCH (movie)-[:WRITTEN_BY|BASED_ON]->(entity)
    WHERE entity:Person OR entity:Novel

RETURN entity
```

Then the returned `entity` correctly relates to Blade Runner:

```
╒══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"entity"                                                  │
╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│{"name":"Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?","id":"102"}│
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│{"name":"Hampton Fancher","id":"100"}                     │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

It seems that the `entity` variable is reset in the second `OPTIONAL MATCH` but only when both the index and constraint are set.

Is this expected and what accounts for this behaviour?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a good illustration of a bug that was fixed in Neo4j 4.2.3, and happens when the label is present in an OPTIONAL MATCH on a previously-bound variable.

From the changelog:

> Fixed a bug where an index scan would be used to solve an OPTIONAL MATCH incorrectly.

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/wiki/Neo4j-4.2-changelog#423

The workaround until the fix was to remove the redundant label.

We highly recommend staying updated to at least the latest patch for your minor version to avoid known and fixed bugs.

Comment: Thanks very much - I have upgraded to Neo4j v4.2.7 and all is good.